# Should I use 为 instead of 是 to mean "is" on a date?

Tags: verbs

Suppose that the following example:

> 报名截止日期**为**2月17日。

In these cases that take a date as the predicate, I usually see 为 instead of 是. Both mean "is" and I already learned 为 is more formal than 是.

However, I feel I have only seen 为 if it takes a date on its predicate. So I wonder whether it must be 为 if you take a date as the predicate or it is just a coincidence.

Also, is there any case that 为 must be used in the usage of “is” or “be”, not just because of "formal"?

Comment: '为' in "印刷术、火药、指南针、‌​纸统称～四大发明" follows the verb 称(be called). It is not equivalent to 'is' but 'as'

Comment: "are called"  ("called as" ?)， "call sth sth"  example of "Double Accusative Construction", which may correspond "V+N+as+N" for some other verbs, "denominate sth. as sth (?)", in the present it might be argued that 为 in E corresponds to "nothing"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 为 http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/466/
>
> [3] [v] be; is; be equivalent to

为 has many different meanings, "is" (是) is just one of them.

You can replace '为' with '是' if you are using it as 'is' in the context.

- 报名截止日期为2月17日。(literary)
- 报名截止日期是2月17日。(colloquial)

> *Also, is there any case that 为 must be used, not just because of "formal"?*

You must use '为' instead of '是' when  '为' doesn't mean 'is' in the context.

For example:

- '为' in "印刷术、火药、指南针、‌​纸统称为四大发明" follows the verb 称(be called). '为' here is not equivalent to 'is' but '**as**'.
- You cannot say "印刷术、火药、指南针、‌​纸[统称**是**]古代中国四大发明"
- But you can say "印刷术、火药、指南针、‌​纸, [**为**]古代中国四大发明" or "印刷术、火药、指南针、‌​纸[**是**]古代中国四大发明"

because [印刷术、火药、指南针、‌​纸] [**is**] [古代中国四大发明]

**EDIT:**

If it is a written announcement, no matter what the predicate is, you should use 为.

Posting '报名截止日期[是]2月17日' or '报名费用[是]成人二十元，老人和儿童半价' is considered bad vocabulary choice (using colloquial term when it should be literary)

If it is an oral conversation, no matter what the predicate is, you should use 是

Telling someone '报名截止日期[为]2月17日' or '报名费用[为]成人二十元，老人和儿童半价' is also considered bad vocabulary choice (using literary term when it should be colloquial)

Comment: Thanks but I meant 为 in the use of “is”. I know it is also used as “as” but it is not in the scope of my question. I updated it to make it clearer.

Comment: If the meaning is 'is',  then using '为' is more literary and  using '是' is more colloquial. As I stated in my answer. They are interchangeable , as the two example sentences showed.

Comment: Yes I know it is. But my question is about the date (or number I think as well). Is there any difference if the predicate is a date or not, regarding which verb to use?

Comment: See my edition at the bottom.

Comment: I see, thanks. But isn’t it OK to use 是 in a literary form? Almost all grammar books for a beginner actually use 是 and don’t introduce 为. I feel they don’t differentiate written and oral contexts...

Comment: It is OK. to  use 是 in literary form, for example,  in written dialogue. But in an announcement, it is not a good choice of vocabulary; It is also OK. to use 为 in oral conversation if you are treating it like a quote or when you read from a written text.